# what is Correct Approach: Json -> ListView OR Json -> Sqlite -> Listview?

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I am fetching data from server in form of JSON and have to show in Listview. Now what I wanna know is , is it better to fetch data from the server every time and directly show in listview. OR I should first retrieve data -> save in sqlite> and then populate it from there.. is it worth to put extra efforts to involve sqlite in app ??

Comment: If you want to do caching, syncing, sharing, or filtering, use SQLite. Otherwise, I really see no point in doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting information from a RESTful API server ( From what it seems ), you have two types of approaches:

**If your server changes that data very often**

- Get the information from the server.
- Populate your Lists (don't save it in SQlite ).

**If your server takes some time to change the data**

- Get the information from the server. (1st time)
- Save it in SQlite
- Populate Lists
- **once in a while**

  - Check in the server, if the current Data Hash is valid
  - if it is, do nothing
  - if it is not, Start over again this cicle.

This is the approach i would make.

Answer (score 3):

[SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) is only used to store the data. if you don't need to store the data on the device, I personally would think that you should just populate the data.

Comment: That's an opinion, not an answer. Not your fault, it's a bad question to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already outlined sqlite is a possibility to store the data when you need it e.g. in offline situations. However I would not recommend to cache your JSON data in sqlite simply because you would have to invest the time to write your storage layer just to get caching. What I would recommend is a library that already caches the data for you and you don't have to care for the storage.
Example: Robospice for Android (https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki/Starter-guide)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show similar data every time then you should go with SQLite option. SQLite will store data in a device locally, every time you have not fetch data from server hence it save response time.

Answer (score 0):

There might be couple of reasons to go for "SQLite caching", but most likely you'd like to load data in background state of the app. Suppose your user presses home button while you're loading your data. Then if you do it directly in Activity, when user comes back to your app, he'll need to wait for the data to load. On the other hand you can move your loading into Service, save data to SQLite and then load data from database in your Activity. This makes your app faster from user's point of view. But you'll have to deal with much more components while developing your app.